# Does there exist an accepted term for the opposite of a holdout?

Tags: experiment-design, terminology, control-group

A holdout is a group of users who are prevented from entering any experiments conducted on a website and kept as a kind of “global” control group. The purpose of a holdout group is to compare the performance of a website without any product improvements to the performance of the website with those product improvements, over some period of time.  To serve its purpose well, the holdout must also remain unexposed to any changes rolled out to the website as a result of A/B testing.

An example might a group of users that are randomized to not receive any marketing e-mails.

Is there an accepted noun for the non-holdout users? I would like to contrast the frozen in time experience of the holdout with the evolving, and sometimes worsening, experience of the remaining users.